# Error by Insert Data into SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, insert

I try to insert data into DB, I get this error by clicking on the Button to Insert it :

```
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TEXT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE mytable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, email TEXT
              #################################################################
              Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
              Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                (near "TEXT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE mytable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, email TEXT)
              #################################################################
```

Comment: The SQL statement itself looks OK. Hidden control characters?

Answer (score 0):

error fixed
the was here below but the Android Studio did not show that by compiling !
one ")" was in the wrong place, that all.

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {  
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE mytable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, email TEXT)");
```